# Android Studio Drawables

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I want to make all drawables files from one image.png
I tried Image asset from android studio but it creates too small images..
Anyone got an idea how can i generate from one png file all drawables files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for. But with this tool you can generate images of multiple sizes:
[Android Assets Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html)

You can upload images, and get icons back, in the sizes of xxxhdpi, xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi

Comment: i tried it but when i download the images they have a black border :( any idea why or how to download them without it?? Thnx